# Running sshd in cygwin: "/var/empty must be owned by root..."

Tags: ssh, sshd, cygwin

I installed OpenSSH on my Windows 7 system so I could tunnel my VNC into it from my Arch machine. However, when I run `/usr/sbin/sshd -D` on the W7 machine, I get the error: `/var/empty must be owned by root and not group or world-writable.`

This is the output of the `ls -All /var`:

```
$ ls -All /var
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 {my_usrnm} None           0 Jul 15 21:39 cache
drw-------+ 1 cyg_server Administrators 0 Jul 15 21:43 empty
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 {my_usrnm} None           0 Jul 15 21:39 lib
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 {my_usrnm} None           0 Jul 15 21:45 log
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 {my_usrnm} None           0 Jul 15 23:36 run
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 {my_usrnm} None           0 Jul 15 21:39 tmp
```

I've tried a few of the permissions fixes and rebooted and reinstalled OpenSSH (by running `ssh-host-config`) at least 10 times, but nothing had fixed it.

How do I fix this error? Thanks!

Comment: Did you install `sshd` through the `cygwin` installer?

Comment: yes @JuliePelletier

Comment: it says owned by `cyg_server` shouldn't it say `root` ?  try `chown root /var/empty`

Comment: other sites I looked at (including this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20473488/1184062), show the owner as cyg_server @JuliePelletier

Comment: It depends on the user the service runs as, and you need to run the `cygwin` shell as an administrator.  If you're already running it as an administrator, I guess your service could be running as the `SYSTEM` user.

Comment: @Jasen:  It is very unlikely that there would be a `root` account on the machine.

Comment: @Jasen:  OP is using `cygwin` which runs on `Windows` and includes adapted software.

Comment: I was running the cygwin shell as admin @JuliePelletier

Comment: @Jasen there is no uid=0 for cygwin

Comment: someone should raise a bug against that error message,

Comment: @ZuluDeltaNiner:  Did you check the system user running the service or simply try `chown SYSTEM /var/empty`?

Comment: @JuliePelletier that command made the service fail to start. It has to run under the cyg_server user

Comment: `ssh-host-config` does not reinstall the ssh daemon; it *reconfigures* it. Did you try reinstalling it from the cygwin.exe executable?

Comment: @WouterVerhelst I reinstalled it twice with no change.

Answer (score 0):

The directory owner and permission are correct.
During configuration use the PrivilegeSeparation option.

Start the demon as service

```
cygrunsrv -S sshd
```

Example of directory permission on a functional system

```
$ icacls $(cygpath -w /var/empty)
E:\cygwin64\var\empty NULL SID:(DENY)(Rc,S,REA,X,DC)
                      MATZERI\cyg_server:(F)
                      BUILTIN\Administrators:(RX)
                      NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(RX)
                      BUILTIN\Administrators:(RX)
                      Everyone:(RX)
                      CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
                      CREATOR GROUP:(OI)(CI)(IO)(RX)
                      Everyone:(OI)(CI)(IO)(RX)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

They are reported in the cygwin way as

```
$ getfacl /var/empty
# file: /var/empty
# owner: cyg_server
# group: Administrators
user::rwx
group::r-x
group:SYSTEM:r-x
group:Administrators:r-x
mask:r-x
other:r-x
default:user::rwx
default:group::r-x
default:other:r-x
```

If there are spurious extra ACL permission the usage of `setfacl -b /var/empty/` could be useful.

Comment: I still get the /var/empty message in sshd.log. I can ssh into that computer from that computer (i.e. localhost), but I can't from my arch machine (it times out).

Comment: My permissions were not correct, so I ran `$ setfacl -s "u::rwx,g::r-x,o::r-x" /var/empty`, which gave me [this output for getfacl (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/UDAYBn3n). However, I still get the /var/empty error.

Comment: what is the output of `icacls $(cygpath -w /var/empty)` ?

Comment: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/S68Ncfiu)